# TransactionScope with Linux

Tags: .net, linux, transactionscope, msdtc, 2phase-commit

I am trying to have WebAPI 2.2 self hosted on Linux enviroment which can be done with Mono, the catch is i am using transaction scope for distributed transactions, so is it (DTC) supported on non windows platforms? also if not is there any workaround or alternative to implement 2pc without DTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDTC is supported on windows only. An alternative to 2PC is to implement a message queue transaction. With this approach, you split the transaction apart and have one for the act of de-queuing the message and one for persisting to durable storage such as a relational database or a NoSQL solution (whatever that may be for your system). With this approach you must factor in message [idempotency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

More about this approach here:

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/05/09/ditching-two-phased-commits/

And you have options regarding what message queuing technology you want to use such as [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/).